# Find row number of a certain index in a ndarray

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, multidimensional-array

I need to find the row and column number of a specific index/item in a ndarray. I found nothing to do this simultaneously, so I tried to achieve this separately. In the shown code I only had at least an idea how to do this for the rows.

For this code the expected output should be `0`. My idea was to iterate over the number of entries with `for i in range(0, len(array)):`. For `i = 0` the wanted item is not found obviously. So `if row != None:` is not fulfilled so the loop should start over. For `i = 1` the condition should be fulfilled and the loop should stop there and give the correct row number. But the output is `ValueError: 2 is not in list`. I found solution to avoid this error but not in the combination with a ndarray.

It feels like I just can't get behind the logic of the combination of the `for` loop and the `if` statement. I am seeking some enlightenment on how this works exactly.

```
array = [[0,1],
         [2,3]]

row = None
item = 2

for i in range(0, len(array)):
    row = array[i].index(item)
    if row != None:
        break
    else:
        continue
print(row)
```

Comment: Is this for an assignment? If not you should probably use a specialized library such as numpy. Let me know if you want a numpy answer

Comment: I just try to code a program in my freetime. As I tried so many things and researched so much so far without finding a solution I would accept any solution. Also I'm a beginner in python and this code just "felt" to be close to the solution so I don't have the experience to evaluate if this is the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a pure python solution:

```
target = 0
for row, lst in enumerate(array):     # loop over rows
    for col, value in enumerate(lst): # loop over values
        if value == target:
            print(row, col)
            # uncomment below if you want to stop after the first match
            # break
```

output: `0 0`

However, I would recommend to use [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)n this is worth learning if you plan to do real ndarray operations:

```
array = [[0,1],
         [2,3]]

# convert to numpy array
import numpy as np
a = np.array(array)

target = 0
# identify the coordinate for all matching values
row, col = np.nonzero(a==target)
```

output (there will be as many values as there are matches):

```
# row
array([0])

# col
array([0])
```

First value:

```
first_match = row[0], col[0]
```

output: `(0, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

To find the row and column of a specific number in a 2d array, loop through the array and use the index function

```
arr = [[0, 1], [2, 3]]

def find(ele):
     for i in arr:
         if ele in i:
             row = arr.index(i)
             col = i.index(ele)
             print("Row: ", row, "Column: ", col)

find(1) # returns "Row: 0 Column: 1"
```